# Symbolic breakpoint for file writing

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, filesystems, uikit

I am trying to further understand when a .framework is writing a particular file.
After calling certain methods on the framework I see a file written onto the app sandbox. 
I am trying to further understand which class or where exactly this file is written from.

I tried installing a symbolic breakpoint on read, fread and the NSFileManager, NSData, NSString APIs that write to a file but these breakpoints are not hit. Is there way to find out/detect filesystem activity and where it is coming from in an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Instruments has a File Activity instrument.  I haven't ever used this on iOS but I'm pretty sure it works there.  That should be able to tell you what you want to know.